# How to parallelize without threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, playframework-2.0, akka

I am developing an application with play framework that performs intensive cpu calculations. These calculations are composed in 40 pieces that have to run in parallel. Now I have done one Akka actor for each of these calculation pieces, and when the calculation is requested 40 new actors are started. My problem is that in the application front I am running a polling service to check whether the calculation has ended or not, and because of the execution of so many threads the cpu gets 100% and the polling service, and of course the whole navigation, lasts aprox 20 seconds, and its a trivial request that in normal circumstances it lasts less than 1 second.

I am running it in an AWS small instance, with just one core. It's part of the problem, but I need to be sure that when the application is in production and the traffic is much bigger, the "backend" calculations will not impact the front experience.

The normal approach with akka is to limit the dispatcher "size" to have less threads and then to have free cpu to process front requests, but I need at least 40 parallel processing elements. I tried to lower the priority to these calculation threads with:

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
```

But I see no effect in performance. My main question is, is there any way that I can logically  paralellize these executions but not creating so many threads?

Comment: I have also tried with Futures instead Actors because they're more recommended to handle asynchronous tasks, but I experienced the same results

Comment: Does the polling service share the same dispatcher?

Comment: No, the polling service uses de default dispatcher and the calculation uses one dispatcher defined by me. 

I think that the akka approach with dispatchers is not recommended for my situation because with 1 cpu core and 40 concurrent calculations I have to set the parallelism-factor = 40.0 which is very ugly and not recommended. Because of that I was searching for some other approach.

Comment: "paralellize these executions but not creating so many threads" well... if you need 40 parallel processing elements then you need 40 threads  (unless part of the process is I/O, which in such case you may need less threads).

Comment: Not just 40 threads, but also 40 CPUs to run them on.  Software can create the illusion of parallel execution, but only hardware can make it actually happen.

Comment: why don't you implement the polling service as an actor which collects all 40 result messages from the calculating actors?

Comment: Thant's the trick, I don't need real parallelism, only the illusion of it jeje with 1 cpu and 40 threads there's no real parallelism because is executing just 1 process at a time, but it's enough for me, that's the reason I wanted some solution without threads.

Comment: Alexei, the polling service is already managed with an Actor (I think the play framework runs in top of akka actors) and does more or less what you say, but the time to respond is very high because of the cpu load.

Comment: Maybe you can replace the polling service with WebSocket? So the frontend doesn't need to poll, but when the calculation is complete, the back server can push the result to the front. So the situation can be better if you use at least two instances, one instance is only responsible for servicing the frontend to the client, and the another one runs backend. The instance running frontend can communicate with the backend with, maybe WebSocket.

Comment: That's a clear possibility, yes, splitting in 2 instances. Maybe is the best approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

It seems that there is no easy way to solve the parallel problem, so the whole idea is to separate your front service with the back calculation.

Firstly, WebSocket. Run WebSocket service on your backend server, and connect to that WebSocket from the frontend. So the front doesn't poll the server, but the back server pushes the results to the front when the calculation is done.

Secondly, run the front service on another instance, even mostly on the client's browser, by using modern JavaScript framework, such as AngularJS.

So the slow back calculation will not affect the performance of front any more, and the front can get results whenever it is done (by communication with the back through WebSocket).

Comment: WebSockets are not a solution for my case I think because I use polling for updating a progress bar and the cpu load problem would be the same.

Running in another instance will be the best approach, but I will always have a "limit" of threads. I still can't execute as much parallel processes as I need.

Comment: Hm.. Speaking of the polling for updating, if you use WebSocket, the server can push the progress to your client, so you don't need polling at all. For cpu loading, as I suggested, you can run the client totally on another machine other than the same server, so the performance of the server won't affect it at all. Yep, for the problem of Parallel processes, you need some framework which can parallel jobs across machines.

Comment: As far as I known I think Akka can distribute actors across the machines border and also allow them to communicate and cooperate. However, no real world experience on that. :)

Comment: If a single instance cannot fulfill your requirement on response time, there are three ways to solve I think: 1. More memory and cpu power of your single instance, 2. Scale your application and thus calculation to multiple instances 3. Optimize your algorithm and use faster framework (not java, maybe something built on c) like node.js. There is simple no other way out. :)